# A question about inclusions of ideals generated by algebraic sets

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $R$ be a ring and  $X_1,X_2 \subseteq \mathbb{A}^n$ two algebraic sets such that $X_1 \subseteq X_2$. Then is it true that $I(X_1) \supseteq I(X_2)$ where

$$I(X) = \{f \in R \, | \,  f(p)=0 \, \, , \, p \in X\} $$

If $f \in I(X_1)$ then $f(p)=0 \, \, \, \forall p \in X_1$ but if $p \in X_1 \Rightarrow p \in X_2$ and so I would rather think that $I(X_1) \subseteq I(X_2)$

Comment: Just think about it intuitively, in terms of functions vanishing on a specified subset. If $f \in I(X_1)$ then indeed $f(p) = 0$ for all $p \in X_1$, but that doesn't tell you anything about the value of $f$ at a point in $X_2 \setminus X_1$.

Comment: right so if $f$ vanishes on the bigger set it will also vanishes on the smaller one (contained in the bigger).. in laymans terms ^^